# WPF Binding MainWindow Control from UserControl, PropertyChanged not fired

Tags: wpf, binding

I'm new to WPF and facing an issue regarding binding.
I have a `MainWindow` with a `Rectangle` that uses binding to change visual attributes. The XAML code is as follows:

```
<Rectangle Height="72" Canvas.Left="1011" RadiusY="6" RadiusX="6" StrokeThickness="2" Width="82" Canvas.Top="8">
    <Rectangle.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding BddState}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Fill">
                      <Setter.Value>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Pictures/BDD_on.png" Stretch="Uniform" />
                      </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>

                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding BddState}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Fill">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="Pictures/Bdd_off.png" Stretch="Uniform" />
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Rectangle.Style>
</Rectangle>
```

I created a view model class to manage the binding:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }


    private Boolean _bddstate;
    public Boolean BddState
    {
        get { return _bddstate; }
        set
        {
            _bddstate = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("BddState");
        }
    }
}
```

The binding works well from MainWindow using:

```
private ViewModel _viewModel = new ViewModel();

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = _viewModel;
    _viewModel.BddState = true;        
}
```

Inside the `MainWindow`, I use a `StackPanel` to load different `UserControl` (the `MainWindow` acts as an header).
My concern is the binding from the `UserControl`; the BddState value changes accordingly but nothing is reflected on `MainWindow` UI.
At the same time, I can see that the handler of the view model is always `null`.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for your support.

Update: Here is the code of the user control:

```
<Grid Background="#FFECECEC" Height="706" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Label x:Name="label" Content="HOME" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="525,8,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="{DynamicResource gray_2}" FontSize="20"/>
    <Label x:Name="label_Copy" Content="General Info" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="441,34,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="{DynamicResource gray_2}" FontSize="18"/>
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="441,214,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="107" Height="36" Click="button_Click"/>


</Grid>
```

for the code behind, it's just the following:

```
 public partial class Home : UserControl
{
    public Home()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ViewModel _vm = new ViewModel();
        _vm.BddState = true;
    }
}
```

When i click the button of Home UC, the handler of ViewModel is null and the binding is not effective on MainWindow rectangle

here some update following Andy's sample (it could help)
by casting mainwindow datacontext it works:

```
 MainWindowViewModel viewModel = App.Current.MainWindow.DataContext as MainWindowViewModel;
        if (viewModel != null)
        {
            viewModel.BddState = true;
        }
```

Comment: "*My concern is the binding from the UserControl*" - where are these UserControls in your code sample?

Comment: For the user control i tried to use:

Comment: ViewModel _vm = new ViewModel();
  _vm.BddState = true;

Comment: Which UserControl? There is none in your question.

Comment: sorry i missed it. I created an usercontrol named "Specification". I load this UC in a Mainwindow stackpanel: (Stackpanel.children.Add(new Specicifation()); then i try to change the rectangle picture from this uc using the code above

Comment: You're asking about why something doesn't work with your UserControls, but then you show us some working code from your MainWindow. That makes no sense. Why don't you show us the code that does not work? E.g. the XAML and code of your UserControl?

Comment: The non working code instantiates another viewmodel. This is another object that is just local to that button click method and has nothing to do with the one in the datacontext of mainwindow.

Answer (score 1):

I modified your markup to:

```
    <Canvas Name="MyCanvas" >
        <Rectangle Height="72"  RadiusY="6" RadiusX="6" StrokeThickness="2" Width="82" Canvas.Top="8">
            <Rectangle.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding BddState}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Green"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding BddState}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Yellow"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Rectangle.Style>
        </Rectangle>
    </Canvas>
```

Which has no reliance on any image and no Canvas.Left.

I get a green rectangle.

Possible reasons you see nothing include:

Your window is narrower than 1011px and Canvas.Left="1011" means your rectangle is not within your window.

Your image paths are not working.

Uniform stretch is creating a problem and the part of the rectangle which has any picture in it is off screen.

I then modified this further to set bddstate true initially via the private backing field in the viewmodel. Added a togglebutton with ischecked bound to bddstate.
That toggles between yellow and green successfully.

Here's a working version involves a usercontrol. I've inherited MainWindowViewModel from a BaseViewModel I had in my test sample.

MainWindow:

```
 <Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Canvas Name="MyCanvas" >
        <Rectangle Height="72"  RadiusY="6" RadiusX="6" StrokeThickness="2" Width="82" Canvas.Top="8">
            <Rectangle.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Green"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding BddState}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Yellow"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Rectangle.Style>
        </Rectangle>
    </Canvas>
    <local:UserControl1 Height="30" Width="100"/>
</Grid>
```

The viewmodel:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private Boolean _bddstate = true;
    public Boolean BddState
    {
        get { return _bddstate; }
        set
        {
            _bddstate = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("BddState");
        }
    }
```

UserControl1

```
    <ToggleButton Width="100" Height="30" Content="Toggle" IsChecked="{Binding BddState, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

BaseViewModel

```
public  class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

There is no code behind.

And this still works.

Comment: The image can be seen if the change of bddstate comes from Mainwindows. There is no visible effect when bbstate change comes from another user control. The problem seems to be linked to datacontext or something like that

Comment: What happen if your toggle button is located in a usercontrol (the rectangle remains in the MainWindow)?

Comment: If the usercontrol is in the window then the datacontext is shared because DataContext is marked to inherit ( down the visual tree ). Which means IsChecked of that togglebutton would still bind to bddstate and it would still work. If you were using viewmodel first so the usercontrol is templated out and the datacontext of the usercontrol is different then you would need to use relativesource to get to the DataContext.bddstate of the parent window.

Comment: I added more markup with a togglebutton in a usercontrol.

Comment: I reproduced your sample and it works perfectly using toggle button, what about changing bbdstate from the codebehind?:

Comment: That would also work. Usually such code would be in the viewmodel but if you really wanted to you could cast the datacontext of mainwindow to MainWindowViewmodel and set the property.

Comment: Many thanks Andy. i added markup to the original question.